# Vue js conditionnal v for data

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

Here my code :

```
<article class="project-card" 
        v-for="item in en.projects"
```

And :

```
import fr from '../assets/datas/fr.json'
import en from '../assets/datas/en.json'

export default {
  data () {
    return {
      languageActive: 'en',
      en: en,
      fr: fr,
```

> If languageActive is 'en', i want to use 'en.projects' in the v-for,
>
> If languageActive is 'fr' i want to use 'fr.projects' in the v-for,

But i read that we can't use a v-if with v-for.

Do you have an idea how to do this ? Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you store the languages as an object, like this:

```
data() {
  return {
    langs: { en: en, fr: fr }, // or { en, fr } ;)
    languageActive: 'en',
  }
}
```

You should be able to key into it like:

```
<article class="project-card" v-for="item in langs[languageActive].projects"
```

Answer (score 1):

Put your `languageActive` in brackets so it will access `en` property:

```
<article class="project-card" v-for="item in [languageActive].projects" 

import fr from '../assets/datas/fr.json'
import en from '../assets/datas/en.json'

export default {
  data () {
    return {
      languageActive: 'en',
      en: en,
      fr: fr,
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use ternary operator in your v-for like this:

```js
<div
      v-for="(item, index) in languageActive === 'en' ? en.projects : fr.projects"
      :key="index">
    {{ item }}
</div>
```

Simple example here: https://codesandbox.io/s/pensive-darkness-bn55w?file=/src/App.vue